# JPA fetch only one level association

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I'm having an issue when trying to fetch all of the "Discount" objects stored in my application. A "Discount" is an object represented by the following class

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "store")
public class Discount {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

// some fields like a description or a percentage providing info about a discount

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_store")
private Store store;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_brand")
@JsonManagedReference
private Brand brand;

// getters, setters, equals and hashcode overriden below
```

As you can see, a Discount object can belong to a Store or to a Brand. I'm ensuring that only one field is set both in my code and in my database with a trigger. In my application, a Discount can be provided both by a Brand (therefore I don't have to create a Discount for each Store of this Brand) or a particular Store can provide its own Discount. My class Store looks like this

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Store extends Entite {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "store", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Discount> discounts;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_brand", nullable = false)
private Brand brand;

// getters, setters, equals and hashcode overriden below
```

As you can see, a Store has a Set of Discounts and belong to a Brand. It extends the class Entite because in my app I also have Sport Clubs and they share some info, but this is not relevant to my problem.
Finally, here is the Brand class

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Brand {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Store> stores;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonBackReference
private Set<Discount> discounts;

// getters, setters, equals and hashcode overriden below
```

My Brand class then have a Set of Store and a Set of Discount.

My problem is that I'm unable to fetch all the Discount with a simple FindAll from my `interface DiscountRepository` extending `JpaRepository<Discount, Long>` because some of the Discount are retrieved within an association. The answer that I get from the FindAll method is the following

```
[
{
    // discount fields such as percentage, ruling, etc
    "store": {
        "id": 75,
        "name": "Nike Store",
        "discounts": [
            75
        ],
        "brand": {
            "name": "Nike",
            "store": [
                75
            ]
        }
    },
    "brand": null
},
{
    // discount fields such as percentage, ruling, etc
    "store": null,
    "brand": {
        "name": "Uniqlo",
        "stores": [
            90
        ]
    }
},
{
    // discount fields such as percentage, ruling, etc
    "store": null,
    "brand": {
        "name": "FNAC",
        "stores": [
            {
                "id": 76,
                // some store fields
                // problem here because Discount are retrieved here and therefore not displayed in the list, only here
                "discounts": [
                    {
                        // discount fields such as percentage, ruling, etc 
                        // for an offer that isn't present in the original list returned 
                        // by the find all method but only here, associated to this Store object
                        "store": 76,
                        "brand": null
                    }
                ],
                "brand": {
                    "name": "FNAC",
                    "stores": [
                        76
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
76
]
```

The problem here is that there's a Discount fetch with a Store and therefore this Discount isn't in the original list that the method returns, but in a Store object associated to a Discount. I tried to add `FetchType.LAZY` to my Store and Discount association but this doesn't resolve the problem.  Therefore is there a way to fetch "only one level association" ? What I mean is, I'd like to retrieve my Discount object but only with the Brand and the Store info, not with the Store or Brand and all its assocations (like its Set of Discount). I hope that I've been clear, do not hesitate to ask me any question.

Comment: The problem is not with fetching. It's with what you return from your REST service and how you configure your JSON serializer. Decide precisely what the response body should contain, then design a class matching with the desired structure, and transform your discounts into instances of that class. You're using JsonIdentityInfo, but you can't deal with what it does.

Comment: My REST service should return a `List<Discount>`. When you say "design a class matching with the desired structure", you're saying that I should create another class having only the fields I want to have ? But, when I retrieve my offer, I want to fetch the brand and the store info, but not their associations (which contain Discount and that's my problem).  Also, I do not understand your last sentence, what do you mean by "you can't deal with what it [JsonIdentityInfo] does" ?

Comment: *you're saying that I should create another class having only the fields I want to have ?*: yes. *when I retrieve my offer, I want to fetch the brand and the store info, but not their associations*: which is a good reason to use a separate class that matches with the structure you want to return, i.e. contains all you want to send back as a response, but not what you don't want to send back.

Comment: *you can't deal with what it [JsonIdentityInfo]*: you chose to use that annotation. Its effect is to replace every occurrence of the discount object with ID 76 in the tree, except the first one, by just the ID 76. But then your question shows that this behavior upsets you. So you shouldn't have used that annotation in the first place.

Comment: Designing another class just to remove data that I don't want because I'm unable to fetch what I want isn't a bad practice? I thought about it when I thought to use a SQL query to only retrieve the fields that I want but this doesn't really seem really clean, does it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I used the JsonIdendityInfo annotation because it allowed me to prevent a StackOverflowException due to circular references. However, I tried to remove it and I'm now fetching all my discounts perfectly but still with their store and their associated discounts (getting those twice then). I'll look for a way to lazy fetch discounts with the store to stop fetching them multiple times. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Lazy loading doesn't mean "no loading". Designing what you precisely want to send is much better than blindly sending whetever your entities contain, and making all the clients of your REST APIs break whenever you change something in your persistence layer. The JSON content is the public contract of your REST API. It shouldn't depend on how you happened to model your persistence layer.

Comment: Therefore, if I understand well, I should design a new class containing: 1st all the info from the Discount that I want to fetch and 2nd the Store info or the Brand info depending on if the Discount is associated to a Store or to a Brand. Should I have attributes in my new class like "storeName", "storeAddress", "storeCity", … ? As this info are already present in my Store class, I find it redundant and isn't this design even more susceptible to break as I will have the fields present both in this new Discount class and in the Store and Adress class (i.e. for a Discount associated to a Store)?

Comment: I can't tell you what your web service should return. You're the one who needs to decide that. What is the "get all discounts" service for. What do the clients of this service use it for? What information do they need to achieve what they want to achieve?

Comment: When calling this service, the client should get a list of all the Discounts. I want each object in my list to contain all the Discount fields, the Store fields and the Address fields for this Store (Address is a class and a Store has only one Address). That’s what I want my service to return when called.

Comment: Then design a class (or set of classes) matching exactly with the JSON you want to send back, and transform your discounts into instances of that class: that will only load what needs to be loaded, and send what needs to be sent.

Comment: Ok, so what you advise me to do is to create a DiscountDTO that will contain all the Discount fields and additional information such as `String storeName`, `String storeAddress`, `String storeCity`, and so on, right? This class will then contain exactly all the information that I'll need and I won't be returning directly Entities as it seems to be a bad practice from what I've read today in other answers.

Comment: A better idea would be to have a StoreDTO in the DiscountDTO

Comment: I thought about it in the first place but logically I should have a `List<Discount>` in my StoreDTO, shouldn't I?

Comment: No, since you **don't** want to send that in the JSON, and the DTO is designed precisely to match with what you want to send in the JSON.

Comment: Ok, but if in the future I have to retrieve all my Store (or a particular one) with their/its Discounts, won't I have to create a StoreDTO having a `List<Discount`?

Comment: Yes. But you'll then create other DTOs, matching exactly with the JSON you want to send in that other, different, response. Or you'll use the same DTOs, but you'll populate them differently, choosing to leave some fields as null because you don't want them to be present in the JSON.

Comment: Ok, this is really clear for me then and it does make sense. Many thanks for your help and your time.